# Get the ID of a Child in a cascade="all" relationship, while adding it to a collection, in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

i have two Entities, "Parent" and "Child", that are linked through a bidirectional one-to-many relationship with the cascade attribute set to "all".
When adding a Child object to the Parent children collection using the code below, i can't get the ID of the persisted child until i commit the transaction:

```
Parent p = (Parent) session.load(Parent.class, pid);
Child c = new Child();
p.addChild(c);
// "c" hasn't an ID (is always zero)
```

However, when i persist a child entity by explicitly calling the session.save() method, the ID is created and set immediately, even if the transaction hasn't been committed:

```
Child c = new Child();
session.save(c);
// "c" has an ID
```

Is there a way to get the ID of the child entity immediately without calling the session.save() method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually depends on the ID scheme that you use.

If you use auto increment fields (eg MySQL, SQL Server), the ID won't be created until the entity is *saved*.

If you use sequences (eg Oracle), the ID will be created when the entity is *persisted*.

I assume then that you have an auto increment field in which case the answer is: no, you can't get an ID without persisting it. That being said, you shouldn't actually *need* that ID most of the time. Relationships with other entities are handled implicitly. I assume then that you want the ID for some kind of URL parameter or form field? Whatever the case, yes you'll need to save it.